# Solr Highlighting with hl.q

Tags: solr

Currently we use solr 3.4 dismax queries throughout the site in order to take fully advantage of it faceting features.

I have now been asked to highlight certain word(s) from the results of the queries.

For example I have the following query which finds 110 documents which is correct:

http://localhost:8080/apache-solr-3.4./select/?qt=dismax&mm=100%25&rows=10&start=0&fq=productType%3Abooks

And if I use the following I get the same number of documents found but there are no highlighted sections:

http://localhost:8080/apache-solr-3.4./select/?qt=dismax&mm=100%25&rows=10&start=0&fq=productType%3Abooks&hl=true&hl.q=java&hl.fl=descriptions&hl.snippets=1000&hl.simple.pre=%3Cb%3E&hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fb%3E&hl.fragsize=120

In the above query I added the highlighting parameters and I used the [hl.q](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.q) which I thought could be used to pass the word(s) i want highlight in my documents without affecting the numFound (110). However this does not seem to be the case, but when I add the q=java the query will return the field with highlighted text but the numFound is affected.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Can Solr achieve this task or is this something I will need to do with the results later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Solr Wiki documentation for the hl.q](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.q) parameter, this is only available in Solr version 3.5 or higher. Since you are running on 3.4 this is probably the explanation for the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks Paige, it was starring right in the face all the time, I just tried downloading 3.6 and my test queries work as i expected. Thanks again!!!